# How do I modify the security descriptor of a windows service as local Admin?

Tags: windows, security, service

My Interactive User account in my company, is member of Local group Administrators. My system is Windows 10.

I want to change the security descriptor of a windows service called service1 with command "sc sdset ".

The current SD (Security Descriptor) of the service is (using the command "sc sd show service1")

```
D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;SU)S:(AU;FA;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;WD)
```

I want to be able to stop the service service1. So I tried to modify the SD adding "WD" to the SD.

But I get the message "Acces denied" in my console even with administrator right.